# Upload Encrypted Image on disk in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

ASP.NET C# Application is uploading Signature images of Employees on server, now we want to these signature image is encrypted format for security reason, and when we use these signature in Application then decrypted these signature images for them.
How we can upload image in encrypted format on server and then later on decrypted image also when ever application use?

Comment: you may want to share: what have you tried?